# MySQL ORDER BY CASE Date ASC/DESC

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case

I have these records on my table:

```
ID  Win    Date
1   NULL   2019-01-15
2   12     2019-01-10
3   NULL   2019-01-12
4   513    2019-01-14
```

I want the order to be:
**win that are null first, ordered by date asc and win that are not null after, ordered by date desc**

So the order would be: **3, 1, 4, 2**

How can i achieve this using order by case or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ORDER BY CASE ...` here:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ...
ORDER BY
  NOT ISNULL(Win),
  CASE
    WHEN Win IS NULL
    THEN `Date`
    ELSE DATEDIFF('9999-01-01', `Date`)
  END
```

This should with for dates before `9999-01-01`. Adjust this value if you'd have latter dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
order by iif(win is null,1,0) DESC, Date DESC
```

Sorry misread the intended order try something like this

```
Order by iif(win is null,1,0) DESC,DateDiff(Day,'1900-01-01',Date) * iif(win is null,1,-1) DESC
```

the idea is to get a value that you can make negative by using an if statement